# How read txt file with special separator and carriage return?

Tags: r

When import txt file in r I have only one line with all values and not two lines. I think the problem is this #@#@#. Could you help me to solve the problem?

Example of the file:

A'~'40337463'~''~'1403289'~'4620851'~'21'~''~'STDLONG'~'A-'~'A-'~'2020-06-08 15:05:59'~''~''~''~''~''~''~''~''~'EU'~''~'New Rating'~''~''~'2023-06-28 00:00:00'~''~''~'DE000A254Z26#@#@#A'~'40337464'~''~'1403282'~'4620842'~'21'~''~'STDLONG'~'BBB+'~'BBB+'~'2020-06-08 15:11:49'~''~''~''~''~''~''~''~''~'EE'~''~'New Rating'~''~''~'2030-12-31 00:00:00'~''~''~'US776743AJ55#@#@#

```
dd <- data.table::fread("200610-204642spRatingDataNoCUSIP.txt", sep = "~", header = F)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello Andrea, I am not sure I understand. You say there'd be two lines. Doesn't that imply that your data includes a line break. But your sample does not have one. Could you clarify?

Comment: And, based on your given data, how should your expected output looks like?

Comment: @MartinGal I edit my answer with output

Comment: @Jan When I use read.table I have dataframe with one row and not two as in the output in my update answer. I think the problem is I don't have a line break but these #@#@#

Comment: It's interessting that there is no `line_sep='#@#@#'` option. At least I didn't find any...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One basic approach could be editing your `.txt`-file and replacing those `#@#@#` with line breaks.

Another approach using `readr` and `stringr`:

```r
df <- read_lines("test.csv") %>%
  str_split("#@#@#", simplify=TRUE) %>%
  read_delim(delim="~", col_names=FALSE) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), str_remove_all, pattern="'"))
```

I named the file `test.csv`, change it accordingly. Acutally I'm not sure if this works with large files, but you could give it a try.

Comment: Thanks this work...It's possible remove all '~' and not only ~

Comment: I added the removal of all `'`.

Comment: I don't have across function. What peckage do you use?

Comment: `across` is part of the newest `dplyr` package. Update your tidyverse to get it.